# Error while compiling custom.pll

Tags: xml, oracle

I got the below error while compiling the custom.pll

Compilation errors on CUSTOM:
PL/SQL ERROR 707 at line 1, column 10
unsupported construct or internal error [2602]

at the below SQL statement the error occurs:

```
SELECT EXTRACT (VALUE (d), 'tokenize/token/text()').getstringval ()
INTO ls_token
FROM TABLE (XMLSEQUENCE (EXTRACT (XMLTYPE.createxml (t_respond),
                                '/tokenize',
                                NULL
                               )
                      )
         ) d;
```

Here is the below function I wanted to add in the custom.pll

```
FUNCTION Xxwv_token (p_no IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  soap_request VARCHAR2 (30000);
  soap_respond VARCHAR2 (30000);
  http_req     utl_http.req;
  http_resp    utl_http.resp;
  launch_url   VARCHAR2 (240);
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        SELECT fpov.profile_option_value
        INTO   launch_url
        FROM   fnd_profile_options fpo,
               fnd_profile_option_values fpov
        WHERE  fpo.profile_option_name = 'TEST WEBSERVICE CALL'
               AND fpov.profile_option_id = fpo.profile_option_id;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
          fnd_message.Set_string ('Profile Setup for URL : '
                                  || SQLERRM);

          fnd_message.Show ();
    END;

    http_req := utl_http.Begin_request (launch_url, 'POST', 'HTTP/1.1');  
    utl_http.Set_header (http_req, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml');    
    utl_http.Set_header (http_req, 'Content-Length', Length (soap_request));   
    utl_http.Set_header (http_req, 'SOAPAction', '');    
    utl_http.Write_text (http_req, soap_request);

    http_resp := utl_http.Get_response (http_req);   
    utl_http.Read_text (http_resp, soap_respond);    
    utl_http.End_response (http_resp);

    SELECT EXTRACT (VALUE (d), 'tokenize/token/text()').getstringval ()
    INTO ls_token
    FROM TABLE (XMLSEQUENCE (EXTRACT (XMLTYPE.createxml (t_respond),
                                    '/tokenize',
                                    NULL
                                   )
                          )
             ) d;


    RETURN '1234567890';
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
             --fnd_message.set_string ('Error : '||SQLERRM);
             --fnd_message.show();
             RETURN '9876543210';
END xxwv_token;
```

Comment: I assume this is a Forms library? What version? If it's an old version, you may be hitting a problem where old versions didn't like newish features in SQL. You may need to hide the SQL behind a view. Or, even better, put all this in a database procedure.

Comment: I agree with Jeffrey.  This belongs in the database.